# Keyboard shortcut or AppleScript to move current tab into a new window

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, tabs

Recent versions of macOS bring tabs to applications that didn’t seem to support tabs before (e.g. [Anki flashcards](https://apps.ankiweb.net/index.html)), via the Dock preference to always prefer opening things in tabs.

Stock apps and some other apps seem to have menu options to “Move Tab to New Window” or “Merge All Windows.” However, Anki (and perhaps others) do *not* have these menu options. I can click to manually move a tab to its own window, but then the 1-tab window can’t be merged back into another window (there’s also no menu option to show the tab bar

I would like to perform these options via a keyboard shortcut (via an AppleScript if necessary) in all applications, independent of the presence of a menu item.

Is this a possibility?